# Liquibase Diff maps LocalTime to Binary

Tags: java, java-8, binary, liquibase, localdate

I am currenty experimenting with liquibase. My changelog file gets generated via `liquibase-maven-plugin` based on my hibernate entity classes. It works so far, but it maps `java.time.LocalDate` to `BINARY(255)`. Is it possible to teach liquibase to use `DATE`, or does it need to be done manually?

I am using

- Spring-Boot 2.1.4
- Liquibase 3.6.3
- Hibernate 5.3.9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `liquibase-maven-plugin` you need to exclude `org.liquibase.ext` dependencies tree for

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
```

with the following

```
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I didnt find time for my private project. I tried out and it works absolutly fine, thank you very much.